# htmlCollection children not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm working on an JavaScript project, that is parsing a XML to fill some input fields.
I was wondering, why this loop section is working perfectly fine in Firefox or Chrome but not in IE...

```
var results = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ResultSet");
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if(results.item(i).getAttribute("queryID") == "get-pos"){
            var rows = results.item(i).children;
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                var columns = rows.item(j).children;
```

my `results` loop is working fine but none of the following... when i look at the debug window in IE it says `rows` would be undefined. 
As far as i can see `.children` is unknown.

After some reasearch i tried `results[i]` instead of `results.item(i)` without any change. (I guess because it's basically the same?)

Why is it not working in IE but in the other browsers? And how can i fix it?

Comment: Which version of IE are you having issues with?

Comment: Ups... forgot that. It's the IE 11

Comment: I'm suprised IE11 doesn't support the children property but childNodes should do the trick instead.

Comment: Do you have a doctype declaration at the top of the page?

Comment: You mean the html doctype? it's <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of IE did not support the [children property on XML documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763798(v=vs.85).aspx).

Try using `childNodes` instead

Comment: I would understand if it wouldn't work with an oder IE. However i'm using IE11... 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp) 

the w3schools page says IE supports the children property since IE9 and even the example is working fine :/

Comment: This is true for HTML Collections however if you look at the equivilent page for [XML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_element.asp) children is not present